# Unknown Index.dat and Storage.dat files in Visual Studio 2010 solution folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, index.dat

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution and two files have mysteriously appeared in the root solution folder a week ago named Index.dat and Storage.dat. They are 28 Bytes and 512 Bytes in size respectively.

The solution is tied to a TFS server but I have never seen these file before in any other solutions.

Any clues as to whether these files could have something to do with VS? I've been working with VS since 2003 and never seen these files before.

Comment: Do you have Database Project in your solution?

Comment: Same issue here... although mine are much smaller. I keep on deleting them but they get recreated. (Edit: It seems that one way they get created it by creating a new solution folder)

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan: Not an SQL server project but a class library with references to entity framework. And at one point I did create an MDF within the project but deleted it later. You think that may be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files are created by Visual Studio if you add a database project to the solution.

Comment: For what purpose do these serve?